# Calling management command from view with file creation

Tags: django, python-2.7

I've a management command which is called from a view via call_command and during the launch of the management command a file gets created on the filesystem.

It seems it's jailed to somewhere. How do i make this creation to be located on the "real" root filesystem.

And where do i find the jailed files?

Django: 1.11.16
Python: 2.7

.

Comment: Anyone would have an idea on this?

Comment: I've the same issue now with python 3.8 and Django 2.2.15 . Apache's version is 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.1 using WSGI . Anyone would have an idea on this? I guess the uploaded files are located somewhere in the memory, they' re readable from the program (but not from a shell), and they're gone after apache2's got restarted.